# Error when retrieving data from HttpResponse.body in a pipe map

Tags: angular

I have an Angular web application with a service to authenticate users with is called from the User login page. It has some actions done in a `pipe(map{})`:

```
login(username, password) {

    return this.http.post<HttpResponse<User>>(`${environment.apiEndPoint}/users/authenticate`, { 
        username, password }, {observe: 'response'})
    .pipe(map(resp => {
        var u: User;
        u = resp.body;
        // do stuff
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(u));
        return u;
    }));
}
```

Recently I have changed the headers to `{observe: 'response'}` in order to access the headers but I have found a problem, although I have verified in the Chrome tools that the post response is in `resp.body`, the compiler is throwing me this error:

```
error TS2740: Type 'HttpResponse<User>' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, username, password, firstname, and 5 more.
```

I have found that if I change `u = resp.body`; with `u = resp.body.body`; the error disappears but then at run time it turns out that `resp.body.body` is undefined while `resp.body` contains the message.

How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: This approach worked for me:  let x = JSON.stringify(resp.body);
 u = JSON.parse(x);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you don't need to specify the `HttpResponse` type, but keep the same params you're using (including `observe: 'response'`)

```
return this.http.post<User>(...)
```

The `resp` will automatically be of type `HttpResponse<User>`, the `resp` being the `HttpResponse` with the headers, and `resp.body` being data of type `User`

Comment: If I do this I am not able to read the headers.

Comment: You'll be able to read the headers off the `resp` obj